# Call to a member function load() using magento tutorial on Weblog

Tags: magento, model

Here is my config.xml
When I displayed $blogpost, it doesn't display anything.
I have no idea why the model doesn't return the data in my database. 
It displays this error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object**

```
<global>    
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magentotutorial_Weblog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>


<models>
    <weblog>
        <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>weblog_resource</resourceModel>
    </weblog>

    <weblog_resource>
        <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource</class>
    </weblog_resource>
</models>
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Magentotutorial_Weblog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function testModelAction() {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
        echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
        $blogpost->load($params['id']);
        $data = $blogpost->getData();
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

Blogpost Model

```
class Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be a model instance Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost')? You need to have model instance Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Blogpost. Share it with us please

Comment: I already added the model

Comment: Ok my next suggestion did you enable this module in app/etc/modules? Somehow Magento can't find your model and this would be caused by different reasons. So provide as much info as you can (all xml files, all models you used in your module)

Comment: yes. the module is already enabled. It's just with the $blogspot, it returns null

Answer (score 3):

Replace below code in app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Weblog/etc/config.xml

```
<weblog_resource>
        <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource</class>
</weblog_resource>
```

with

```
<weblog_resource>
         <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <blogpost>
                    <table>blog_posts</table>
                </blogpost>
            </entities>
    </weblog_resource>
```

create Blogpost.php at app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Weblog/Model/Resource/

Put below code in Blogpost.php file

```
<?php
class Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost', 'blogpost_id');
    }
}
```

Run your code..

For more information :- [Click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics)